# Google Maps API - renders static map rather than dynamic

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am adding a google map to my site, and i've added exactly the same code as from the google maps api documentation but my map appears as a static map without marker (with the correct center point which is a good start) instead of a dynamic draggable map with marker and controllers.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Code is below although I'm fairly sure the code is fine since it's straight from the google maps api site.

```
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: [Your code works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/a3DC6/). Make sure that you're calling the API properly.

Comment: Found this hidden elsewhere in the code... once removed it's all good! `<script src="https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/16/2/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`